# Gravity Simulation Isn't Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, simulation

I am trying to make a simulation of gravity and the sort. I am just starting off right now, but I've already encountered a problem I can't seem to find the answer to. I am trying to make it so my particle speeds up exponentially by the gravity variable using another variable. But when I run this code, it makes the particle[0].y = NaN. Help is very appreciated.

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var gravity, objectDensity, force, parVelo;
gravity = 9.8;
function Object(mass, x, y, w, h) {
    this.m = mass;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
};
var particle = [];
particle.push(new Object(10,10,10,20,20));
function draw() {
    parVelo += gravity;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    for(let i = 0, len = particle.length; i < len; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(particle[i].x,particle[i].y,particle[i].w,particle[i].h)
    particle[i].y += parVelo;   
}
}
setInterval(draw,1000);
```

Comment: You didn't set an initial value to `parVelo`

Comment: Wow... basic coding techniques. I really overlooked that. I feel kinda embarrassed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `parVelo = 0;` probably at the same time as setting the initial value for `gravity`.